# xPage viewPanel - Calculate datasource connection to many databases

Tags: xpages, xpages-ssjs

I am new to xPages and am working on a proof of concept app. We have hundreds of Notes Db's built from a template and the xPage app needs to access view and document data from any one of these databases. Currently in an xPage that contains a viewPanel I can connect to any of the databases and the view that contains the data to display using the static option. I can also go to the source and change the databaseName property and see the data from that database also.

xp:dominoView var="view1"
"viewName="site-lookup"                 databaseName="Studies\LUME\LUME2939.nsf

But when I try to access any of the databases using computed SSJS, not a static method I am not getting the data or I get errors and no page display.

The users would select a project from a listBox on a landing page and I then create session variables for the projectID and database path to the project database. I have confirmed this works just as expected.

I have tried some example code from xPagesCheatSheet.com (see below ) but nothing is working as I expect. I have spent several hours scouring the boards and other sites looking for an answer and have not found one yet. I am hoping someone here might be able to shed some light on my dim mind and point me in the right direction. Thanks for any assistance you might provide.

[Code to change the databaseName for a view panel.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4oBkw.jpg)

Comment: Please post the code that throws the error. Most likely a minor twitch to get you going.

Comment: While you are still at PoC phase, have a look here: http://www.notessensei.com/blog/2015/10/domino-grunt-json-and-yeoman.html - might save you a lot of headaches down the road.